# Mongoose change stream "hasNext()" behavior always is true

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My problem is while the loop is never terminated.

This my changeStream object:

```
const changeStreamIterator = userModel.User.collection.watch(filter, {
     fullDocument: "default",
     startAtOperationTime: startAtOperationTime,
     readPreference: "primary",
});
```

Read results with this code:

```
   while (await changeStreamIterator.hasNext()) {
               
           let change = await changeStreamIterator.next();

           console.log("change");
   }
.
.
.
```

after the above code, my code not resumed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A change stream is infinitely long. If you make a loop iterating it, this loop will be an infinite one.

Use patterns available in node to do other work concurrently.